# skstoreproductviewcontroller: how to open "rating and review" at launch

Tags: ios, rating, storekit, review

I see some tutorial about `SKStoreProductViewController`, such as:
[Open a list of my apps in the App Store within my App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739703/open-a-list-of-my-apps-in-the-app-store-within-my-app)

However, it always opens `SKStoreProductViewController` with "Details" at launch, how can I open "rating and review" programmatically

Comment: This appears to not be possible in iOS6.  But the iOS5 solution of calling the URL does appear to launch the App Store in the rating page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654144/direct-rate-in-itunes-link-in-my-app/4382571#4382571

Comment: What about IOS 8.4. Any luck?

Answer (score -1):

Below code snippet will open the reviews & ratings section on native AppStore app

```
struct AppStoreURLs {
    static let templateReviewURLiOS8 = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?id=%@&onlyLatestVersion=true&pageNumber=0&sortOrdering=1&type=Purple+Software"
}


func showAppReivewScreen(_ appId: String?)  {

        guard let applicaitonIdentifier = appId, (applicaitonIdentifier.isEmpty == false) else { return }

                let reivewURL = String(format: AppStoreURLs.templateReviewURLiOS8, applicaitonIdentifier)

        if let url = URL(string: reivewURL), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {

            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly : false], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        }

    }
```

call this function using application identifier

```
self.showAppReivewScreen("951627022")
```